# Android TabLayout CompatTextView can not be resolved

Tags: android, android-support-library

I was using [TabLayout](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.java), but after copying it in my src, I am getting following errors:

(1) `android.support.v7.internal.widget.CompatTextView can not be resolved`

(2) `styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field` Though I checked other answers in stackoverflow, but failed to get proper solution. I already imported android.R

(3) I checked that in my android-support-v7-appcompat.jar the class **CompatTextView** is missing. How this can be possible.

(4) Will there be any legal issue if I copy the TabLayout class given by google for my app?
Please help.

- **Update:**
  I added `import android.support.v7.appcompat.R;` instead of `android.R` and getting following several error like `Widget_Design_TabLayout cannot be resolved or is not a field` `TabLayout_tabIndicatorHeight cannot be resolved or is not a field` `TabLayout_tabIndicatorColor cannot be resolved or is not a field` etc. Please suggest.

Comment: why are you copying that in your src when you can access it using library? Because this class is dependent on other required things!

Comment: ok, but what is the library ? I want to import it all.

Comment: TabLayout is part of design support library, you just need to include it your build.gradle file to access its classes and resources!

Comment: I have Android Support Library 22.2.1 is Installed in SDK Manager. No where I can find TabLayout class or design library folder. Am I missing something, can you please guide. Thanks for help.

Comment: sorry Paresh, I got it now... it is C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\design. I imported. Many many thanks for quick response and help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting comments into the answer as you have found them helpful and able to resolve your issue.

I don't know why are you importing/copying it manually in your project, because TabLayout is part of design support library, you just need to include its artifact ID in your build.gradle file to access its classes and resources!

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:+' //replace + with latest version
```

Comment: Thanks, I progressed a lot from yesterday on Tab implementation correctly. :)

Comment: Just to give you more reference, I am writing a [tutorial series on "Design support library"](http://www.technotalkative.com/lets-explore-android-design-support-library/) on my blog, do check it out if interested.

Comment: @PareshMayani Can u pls help me here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35456147/tablayout-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-eclipse