# TabLayout cannot be resolved to a type- Eclipse

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout

I want to create a `TabLayout` with `ViewPager`. I'm using api version 22. I'm getting this error

> TabLayout cannot be resolved to a type

I'm using Eclipse for development.

[image: SDK manager]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were remaining with adding support library in your project.

Before use the design support library, you have to import support-v7-appcompat library from android-sdks\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat. Then, you have to:

- create an android library project in eclipse for design support
  library
- put the contents of directory
  android-sdks\extras\android\support\design in the design support
  library project
- Link appcompat-v7 library to design support library project
- Link support library project from your project.

You can not use directly the jar android-support-design.jar because
   you need some resources too (this is the reason of aar format).

For more info just check [Error in styles_base.xml file - android app - No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530415/error-in-styles-base-xml-file-android-app-no-resource-found-that-matches-the)

Comment: I have imported appcompat from v7.But I don't have `design` folder in the path `android-sdks\extras\android\support\design`.

Comment: @Jas You have to update your android libraries using SDK manager

Comment: @Jas Time to switch to Android Studio :)

Comment: I know :( But i need to make this work now.Please see the screenshot of my SDK Manager attached in question.Which one should I update?